# avoiding tracking of some links

Tags: civimail, tokens

The doc's give this example: "you may wish to avoid tracking who has clicked on the "how to deal with drug issues" link on a specific mailing".

Is there a way of specifying which link(s) are not to be tracked? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is only a per mailing basis: you can track all the emails in one link or none.

However, a workaround might be to add a token as a parameter you do not want to be tracked. eg:

```
<a href="https://how2deal.drug/issue#{contact.hash}">Not tracked link</a>
```

So here we put the contact hash, that is not going to mean anything and is not a private information, and you put it after the #, so the browser will not send it to the webserver and won't be in the server log. And because civimail does not track links with token, you should be good.

Let me know if it works for you.

X+

Comment: @user4454 seems likethis would be useful for the documentation.

Comment: I don't even see how to track none of the links in a mailing, which is what I want. That would be helpful in the documentation (under "privacy") too.