# Click-throughs not being recoreded

Tags: developer

We sent out a mailing this week - one in a series - and have so far had 1400+ opens from a list of 2600 or so.  However, despite the URL Click-through tracking being set to "On" we have only recored 3 click-throughs.  Data we have recorded in Google Analytics for the same mailing is much higher.

What reasons could there be for the click-through tracking not to work?

Comment: Did you sent an email to yourself, and tried the click-through link. What happens if you do?

Answer (score 2):

Not all URLs get magically converted to being click-through tracking ones. Most internal ones, for example, do not (e.g. a link to a donation page with the cid and hash).

If you look at the email being generated (look at the actual html of the email, using something like 'show original'), you should be able to see which ones should be click-through ones because their path looks like this:

/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php

Here's a related inverse question:
[avoiding tracking of some links](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17748/avoiding-tracking-of-some-links)

If your links really are click-through tracking ones and people are clicking on them, they'll get counted (unless the click-through links are badly formed due to an incorrect configuration, but that seems unlikely if you're not noticing a lot of other errors).

**Update**

If you go into your email client and copy a message you recieved from CiviCRM and then paste that as a new message into CiviMail, you will be copying the magically-generated click-through tracking urls from that past mailout (and ones that are specific to you). The new mailout will generate click-through tracking for the previous mailout, all as if it was you that clicked on the links. This is a super bad idea, don't do it.

In a better future world, CiviCRM should give you a big red warning if you try to directly include urls of the form /modules/civicrm/extern/url.php in your message source.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

The links do appear to have the /modules/civicrm/extern/url.php path extensions, so it's really curious as to why the clicks aren't being counted.

I received the e-mail myself and clicked several of the links, but none of those clicks has registered in the report.  Fingers crossed this was a one-off problem - other e-mails we have sent recently (although they are created in a slightly different way) have been registering clicks as expected.

Comment: I'm intrigued by "although they are created in a slightly different way". Can you describe how the non-functioning click-throughs are created differently? If those urls are being hit and correctly redirect, then it's hard to imagine why they might not get counted.

Comment: The e-mail we're having problems with is "hand-crafted" (probably based on the template of a previous one with the links, any images and text changed), whereas we have regular weekly e-mails where the content is created in another system and then transferred into CiviCRM to send out. After the "/modules/civicrm/extern/url.php" part of the URL there's a "?u=xxx&qid=" (where the xxx must be the unique tracking code? And there's nothing in the qid bit). In the e-mail where the links aren't being tracked, the "&qid=" is showing as "&amp;qid=xxxx", so I wonder whether that's the problem?

Comment: And how those links would have got messed up?

Comment: Perhaps someone is grabbing the source of an civimail delivered email and then pasting it in as the source of a new one? You definitely don't want to do that. Instead, you want to use the feature within CiviMail that lets you use "Re-use" a past mailing. What you're likely doing is inflating the click-throughs of the wrong mailout.